# I need a language dictionary

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, language-agnostic, dictionary, spell-checking

I need to add dictionary facilities to an Asp.net MVC app. Does anyone know a library that I could use? Where can I get word definitions from?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How can this question be taged asp.net and asp.net-mvc and then as "language agnostic".  Its either one or the other.

Comment: I think he probably meant real languages (english, spanish etc.) when he put in language-agnostic?

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, ASP.NET and ASP.NET MVC are not languages.  They can both be written in C# or VB.

Comment: At the risk of stating the more obvious:  Language Agnostic == Used with any Language && Language Agnostic != C# || VB || DLR ( compatible MVC && Asp.net languages )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it depends on what you want to do. 
if you're trying to add a reference of an actual dictionary of words to use for your application then you'll have to create your own to define the words that you want to use. 
if you're trying to find the library that contains the data type dictionary then you should try 
System.Collections.Generic, or System.Collections.Specialized

Answer (score 0):

If its still relevant for you, It's not a 'library' but on [Dicts.info site](http://www.dicts.info/) you can find raw dictionary files you could use inside your application.

You can also find [bilingual dictionaries](http://www.dicts.info/uddl.php) for various languages or even [categorized vocabulary](http://www.dicts.info/vocabulary/), and even more...

*Watch out to respect their respective licences.*